# CSS / JavaScript / Image minify / compress with code instead of tool

Tags: javascript, css, image, compression, minify

Is it possible to compress / minify  CSS, JavaScript, images only with code (no tools)?

Sorry as this question is not related to coding but this is something I have been asked in a interview and couldn't find it on Google.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Compress a file is to reduce his size and a image is a file that contains an a*b number of pixels in byte code. So, I can think about two ways to achieve it: 
    -    Reduce image size and quality 
    -    Reduce image size maintaining quality

To do the first one you could use sentences like this, from PHP:

```
    $info = getimagesize($source);
    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    imagejpeg($image, $image."(1)", $quality);
```

The second one is a bit more tricky. It involves algorithms like Huffman's code or RLE (Run Length Encode) which you can pass to code.